# Remove dropdown shadow

Tags: css, menu, shadow

I am creating a website for a client and would like to remove the blue "shadow" on the dropdown menus. i think the code i must edit is as follows:

```
.main_nav ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 150px;
    z-index: 9999;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

can you please assist me in this matter.
http://makeskate.wpengine.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this from your css codes :

```
.main_nav li:hover a, .link-active, .current-menu-item a {
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}
```

And delete background from here :

```
.skill_set, .soft_skill span, .submit_button, .main_nav li:hover a, .link-active, .current-menu-item a, .main_nav ul.sub-menu, .button, #submit, .wpcf7-submit, .post .date, .tags a, .entry-footer li a:hover, .post-content .wp-caption, .comment .comment-meta .comment-reply-link:hover, #searchsubmit {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #34799E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-shadow:none` to your `.main_nav li:hover a` styles

```
.main_nav li:hover a, .link-active, .current-menu-item a{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the blue background color, then use the below style

```
.main_nav li:hover a, .link-active, .current-menu-item a{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);  // to remove the blue background and add transparent background
}
```